# How to check spark-scala case class is null or not?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-option

I am new to spark-scala, I have a case class as below

```
case class Session(src: String,
                      id: String,
                      meterId: Option[Long],
                      computerId: Option[String],
                      startTime: Long,
                      endTime: Long,
                      memberId: String,
                      isComplete: Boolean)
```

How to implement the case class is null/empty check on this?

I did as below by looking out online, but its not working

```
  def isPCSessionEmpty(pCSession: Session): Boolean = {
    pCSession.productIterator.forall {
      case None => true
      case Some(x: PCSession2) => isPCSessionEmpty(x)
      case _ => false
    }
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by "empty"?

Comment: To check if something is null, you just write `... == null`.

Comment: if you have a variable `s` of type `Session`, just do `s==null` for a null check

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you define your class to be empty, e.g. do you mean some mandatory fields are missing, all fields are null and/or option are set to `None`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for response, In scala the standard practice is empty/null check has to be avoided by using `null` key word, instead `Option` is used. I want implement empty ness check using scala-option

Comment: Alright - so using `Option`s for optional fields is the right way to go. What is the condition for the function `isPCSessionEmpty` to return true? (e.g. at least one field is absent?)